# How to replicate this text scattering effect in Adobe Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, typography, effects

In the following picture (by /u/Your_Post_As_A_Movie on Reddit), how would one create the effect of the symbol scattering? Does Photoshop allow one to scatter text with similar parameters as brushes? Or would all the individual graphemes need to be placed manually?

[image: "Miniland" fake poster by Your_Post_As_A_Movie on reddit]

(note: I am using CS6)

Comment: I'm not sure how that was done, but it wouldn't have been done by hand. Most probably either a plugin or script.

Comment: I personalyy would be using a real 3D program there with a good render engine, and some compositing in Photoshop afterwards.

Comment: For reference, here is the original he used: http://m.imgur.com/A4wsrH1 so I don't think 3d was involved at least for that part. As for the text effect, can it be done entirely within Photoshop?

Comment: It certainly could have been done by hand.

Comment: @DA01 it _could_ have been done by hand, but so could anything. There's no reason it would have been done by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Create Brush with symbols you want shown
- Select brush you created and edit its settings

[image]

- Edit the brush tip shape, add spacing, change the angle

[image: Brush Tip Shape]

- Edit shape dynamics. Make the size jitter, put  min amount of size. Also make the angle jitter.

[image]

- Make sure it scatters (on both axis). That way on one click you get lots of the symbols in random places.

[image]

- Play with these settings until you achieve the look you want. The **trick** is to look at the original image and determine what is randomized (angle jitter, size, scattering). Play with the settings until it looks like you want it to look.
- Don't worry about the transparency randomness. You can control that by creating two layers. One with bigger size symbols, the other with smaller. then the layer that is supposed to be "behind", you give it transparency.

(I know the image is not exactly the same, I pretty much left the settings as default.)

[image]

Hope it helps.

Comment: To clarify, did you create a brush containing a bunch of scattered characters or create individual brushes for different characters and then apply the same scattering settings?

Comment: @JamesHarrison I created a single brush with scattered symbols. Not too far apart, not too close.